# SDL/C++: How do I move a rectangle smoothly but randomly?

Tags: c++, sdl

So I have a rectangle in a 640x480 window, and I'd like it to just move about randomly. I don't want it to *skip* to a different spot, it needs to be continuous movement.

I know I need random numbers for this, but doing something like

```
rect.x += rand() % 2*stepsize - stepsize;
rect.y += rand() % 2*stepsize - stepsize;
```

to get random movements doesn't really make the rectangle move about on the screen smoothly, it just kind of jitters back and forth in the same place.

What's an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the random perturbations to your velocity or acceleration vectors instead of directly on the position.

Or choose random random positions within a certain radius of your location and accelerate towards those.